# would happen vs would have happened

Tags: grammar

> What **would happen** if Mark Zuckerberg was born in India?
>
> What **would have happened** if Mark Zuckerberg had born in India?

Which one of these two is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark Zuckerberg was born in the past, so you would use past tense:

> What would have happened if Mark Zuckerberg had been born in India?

Asking what **would happen** if a certain event occurred means that the event hasn't happened yet.

Comment: can I say, What would happen if Mark Zuckerberg stopped the facebook.

Comment: Remove the word "the" and it's fine.

Comment: ...and capitalize the word _Facebook_.

Comment: @JNRaju "stopped"? That really doesn't mean what you need it to mean... You could say "shut down"... "closed"... either would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

This one is what you typically find in your typical English grammar textbook (and that's perfect grammar):

> What would have happened if Mark Zuckerberg had been born in India?

But more colloquially (daily English), you can just say:

> What would have happened if Mark Zuckerberg was born in India?